# What does 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable' mean?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am developing a simple house prices prediction machine learning model. I get this error when running and don't know why. I have read that that it means that I am trying to call a numpy array as a function but don't really understand what this means as I dont see it happening in my code. Here it is:

```
Path = "housedata"
Name = "data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(Path, Name))
df2 = df.apply(preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
df2 = df2.drop(columns=["date", "yr_renovated", "street", "city", "statezip", "country"])

predictors = df2.drop(columns=["price"])
target = df2["price"].values()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(predictors, target, 
                                                    test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
print (regr.score(x_test, y_test))
```

The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "housemodel.py", line 19, in <module>
    target = df2["price"].values()
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Anyone have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: `values` is an attribute, not a method.  Delete the parentheses.

Comment: A `callable` is a function or method.  `foo()` calls `foo`.  `df.values` produces an array, without needing the `()`.  The `()` aren't needed, and end up producing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, `df["price"].values` returns a `numpy.ndarray`, and then `()` attempts to call  an array (which cannot occur; only methods/functions can be called). Drop the `()`:

```
target = df2["price"].values
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get this type of error `... object is not callable`.  It means that you are calling an attribute instead of method

In order to explain it better. Consider this example.

```
class Person(object):
  """ Person class """

  def __init__(self, name, age):
    """ Initialize Person"""
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def getname(self):
    return self.name

  def getage(self):
    return self.age

  profession = 'Oncologist'


doctor1 = Person('Dr. Prabhaharan', 45)
# Gives correct output
print(doctor1.profession)

# Gives correct output
print(doctor1.getage())

# Gives a similar output which you got.
print(doctor1.profession())
```